# Eloquent (Laravel) result to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get result from Eloquent (Laravel 4.2) into simple array, so I con make `array_diff`.

In documentation I found `all()` function, which gives result to array, but the are also things I cant have, because of `array_diff`.

I have :

```
$curCentres = Doccentre::where('r_document', $document)->select('r_id')->get()->all();
```

but this return something like:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(Doccentre)#1125 (20) {
         ["table":protected]=> string(9) 
            "doccentre" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(4) 
            "r_id" ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) 
            ["connection":protected]=> NULL 
            ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) 
            ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) 
            ["attributes":protected]=> array(1) {
                 ["r_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
            } 
            ["original":protected]=> array(1) { 
                ["r_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
            }
            ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } 
            ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } 
            ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } 
            ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } 
            ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } 
            ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> string(1) "*" 
            } 
            ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } 
            ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } 
            ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } 
            ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } 
            ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL 
            ["exists"]=> bool(true) 
        } 
    [1]=> object(Doccentre)#1124 (20) { 
        ["table":protected]=> string(9) 
        "doccentre" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(4) 
        ....
}
```

All I need is :

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Is there any way to get it? I also tried `toArray()`, but it makes only errors.

Comment: You can use: https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/diffing-eloquent-collections-in-laravel-4 which is cool, because you can still have your collections (which are **arrays on steroids**).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `lists` to retrieving a list of column values:

```
$curCentres = Doccentre::where('r_document', $document)->lists('r_id');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But without toArray(), because lists return array already.